# AngularJS Karma - How to trigger directive attr.$observe in tests?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to test a directive where by I have a section of code that observes an attribute:

```
    function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {

        attrs.$observe('myattr', function() {
            console.log('do something');
```

I have a test that does this:

```
var html = '<my-directive></my-directive>';
var scope;
var element;

beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {}));
beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
}));

describe('after being compiled', function() {

    it('my test', function () {
        element[0].setAttribute('myattr', 'hello');
        console.log(element); // shows that myattr is set properly
        scope.$digest();
        // the console.log is not triggered, why?
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, it is different: You have to add the attribute to the directive:

```
var html = '<my-directive myattr=""></my-directive>';
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/I2nngQtEUyxBbcGrdtTJ?p=preview

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. I mean do the $digest which would call $apply anyway but still tried $apply on its own and no luck.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The only output is from the initial page load, not from the unit test.

Comment: @stevek No, I didn't. As I noted in my comment, the right answer in my mind is to test the linked function and the changing of the attribute, rather than testing whether angular will listen for changes I have updated this Plunkr to make it clearer that it doesn't work. http://plnkr.co/edit/DUvu221lBCZyZYs8XsiC

Answer (score 0):

In general, I prefer to give the change handler a name (make it a member of the directive, or better yet put all that logic in an embedded controller) and then call it directly in your test. Otherwise you're testing the angular infrastructure which doesn't gain you anything. Unit tests should trust that the framework works (that's why we use mocks) and test your own code. Functional and integration testing will tell you whether you've set up the framework right.